# How I can Add Jest as a dev Dependency as first task

Tags: jestjs

### Task 1: Add Jest as a devDependency

Open terminal. Make sure that it's pointing to `jest-testing` directory.
Install the jest npm package using the npm install command and the --save-dev flag.
Verify that the installation was completed successfully by opening the package.json file and confirming that the "devDependencies" entry lists jest similar to the following:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.0.0"
}
```

### Task 2: Update the test entry

In the package.json file, locate the "scripts" entry, and inside of it, update the test entry to `jest`.

### Task 3: Code the timesTwo function

Open the timesTwo.js file and add a function named `timesTwo`. The function should take number as input and return the value 2 multiplied by the number.
Export the timesTwo function as a module.

### Task 4: Write the first test

Code a test call with the following arguments:

1. The description that reads: "returns the number times 2".
2. The second argument should expect the call to the timesTwo function, when passed the number 10, to be 20.

### Task 5: Run the first test

With the terminal pointed at the `jest-testing` directory, run the test script using npm.

Comment: _"using the npm install command and the --save-dev flag"_, as the instructions tell you. If you're unfamiliar with a command, read the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install

Answer (score 0):

Task 1: Add Jest as a devDependency

use comands

```
cd jest-testing
node --version
npm --version
npm init -y
npm install --save-dev jest
```

Task 2: Update the test entry
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sytJy.jpg)

Task 3: Code the timesTwo function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUvBs.jpg)

Task 4: Write the first test
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWPnL.jpg)

Task 5: Run the first test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIOnR.jpg)